# Call function when save setting/option in custom admin page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I would like to call a function when a I save a setting/option in a custom admin page.

Comment: Can you update your question with more details, such as which setting you're referring to, how you're adding it, etc

Answer (score 1):

Every function hooked to `admin_init` will be called after you save settings in the admin page. You should add some extra check of conditions to trigger your code on correct page. For example:

is this the setting page?
is set `$_REQUEST` with values from options page  etc...

Comment: You're right. When save settings the function hooked is called. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

When save settings the function hooked is called. The solution is check in this function this:

```
// check if the user have submitted the settings
 // wordpress will add the "settings-updated" $_GET parameter to the url
 if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
   // add the function called
   your_function();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook into `save_post` ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/ ).

Within your function, to see if you're working with the option page you want, use `get_current_screen()` ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/ ).

You can then look through the $_POST/$_GET variables you're receiving.

Don't forget to use a nonce and filter the incoming values! ☝